# Trying to send email from google sheets with apps script, but blank cells give unwanted output

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to send some values in table to an email, the problem starts when it sends the date, I want it in this format "dd-mm-yy"

```
var fecha = new Date(registro.getRange("c16").getValue());
var fechaF = Utilities.formatDate(fecha, "GMT","DD-MM-YYYY");
```

The above code is used to transform the date, but when a cell that is a date is empty it sends me a date totally random.

It is table with multiple dates, and if I write the first it sends exactly the same, but if there is nothing it sends me a random date, and I want to send nothing, because having these dates in the email could be confusing.

What can I do to set the format, but also to not send anything if it is empty

[image]

Here is an example what is send to the email

Comment: Its not randome. It is the start of [unix time](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) just filter out the blank cells or some if statement. if(cell == "") then null else new Date(cell)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i also thought it was not random but i dont know how to name it, could you tell me where can i find information about if or conditions? i was looking for information but it wasnt clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var fechaF = registro.getRange("c16").isBlank() ? "No Date" : Utilities.formatDate(new Date(registro.getRange("c16").getValue()), "GMT","DD-MM-YYYY");
```